# errror - int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'PngImageFile'

Tags: deep-learning, keras

Hi I'm a new of deep learning.
Now I'm working on project about autonomous driving by using keras and tensorflow.
Our team use racing image as input data and steering angle as output data.
I tried to build Sequential model in Keras but I have some problem.
I don't know what it is. I just guess that input data, image might cause the problem.
Here is my code.

```python
#Import Keras and ...
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, activations
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import keras.losses
from keras.utils import np_utils


import os
from Read_Data import read_label, read_images

#Path
image_path = 'C:/Users\JUNG HYEONG SEOK/Keras/Cutted Training Image'
text_path = 'C:/Users\JUNG HYEONG SEOK/Keras'

#Parameters
img_width, img_height = 280, 70
img_list=os.listdir(image_path)
batch_count=10
batch_size=100

#Train Data
x_train=read_images(img_list, batch_count, batch_size)
y_train=read_label()


#Model
model = Sequential()


#1st layer
model.add(Convolution2D(24, (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(280,70,1)))

#2nd layer
model.add(Convolution2D(36, (5, 5), activation='relu'))

#3rd layer
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu'))


#Flatten
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

#Compile
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)
#Run`enter code here`
model.fit(np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train), epochs=5, batch_size=100)

def read_images(img_list, batch_count, batch_size) : # Read the training images by batch size

    images = []
    batch_index = batch_count * batch_size

    for name in img_list[batch_index : (batch_index + batch_size)] :

        img = Image.open('%s%s'%(image_path, name))
        images.append(img)

    return images
```

if i add np.array to x_train, the error is 'int argument must be a string, a bytes like object or a number, not 'PngImageFile'
or i just used x_train the errer is 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Addtionally, Read_Data is just below

```python
import os
from PIL import Image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

image_path = 'C:/Users/JUNG HYEONG SEOK/Keras/Cutted Training Image/'
text_path = 'C:/Users/JUNG HYEONG SEOK/Keras/'


img_list=os.listdir(image_path)


def read_label() : # Read the whole training labels

    Text_steering = open("%sSteering_Data.txt" % text_path, 'r')

    Steering_label = Text_steering.read().splitlines()

    return Steering_label

def read_images(img_list) : # Read the training images by batch size

    images = []

    for name in img_list:

        img = Image.open('%s%s'%(image_path, name))
        images.append(img)

    return images
```

And image is png file which is 280x70 sized file
thanks

Comment: can you post the error

Comment: if i add np.array to x_train, the error is 'int argument must be a string, a bytes like object or a number, not 'PngImageFile' or i just used x_train the errer is 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: What are you using to load images? What is this Image object?

Comment: I think the problem is about converting the images. Where do  these read_label and read_images functions come from? what is the Read_data module?

Comment: If so... is that the problem that converting from image to array?